# Icinga - How can I set custom contacts for services per hosts

Tags: nagios

I would like to set different contacts for same service based on from which host the service is called.

I've tried to use macro, but it gets translated only when command is called. 
Then I've tried to edit command itself, but I think that variable CONTACTEMAIL is managed internally by icinga. I don't feel comfortable with adding only pure emails to some custom macro defined in HOST.

```
define command{
    command_name    notify-service-by-email
    command_line    /usr/bin/printf "%b" "***** Icinga *****\n\nNotification Type: $NOTIFICATIONTYPE$\n\nService: $SERVICEDESC$\nHost: $HOSTALIAS$\nAddress: $HOSTADDRESS$\nState: $SERVICESTATE$\n\nDate/Time: $LONGDATETIME$\n\nAdditional Info:\n\n$SERVICEOUTPUT$\n" | /bin/mail -s "** $NOTIFICATIONTYPE$ Service Alert: $HOSTALIAS$/$SERVICEDESC$ is $SERVICESTATE$ **" $CONTACTEMAIL$
    }
```

Did anyone try/solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can define your contact on the host and delete it from services. This way every service in that host will inherit its contacts, if you define a contact again in the service it will ignore the previous one.

If the contacts depends on each service and not host, you will have to define same service for each host/contact.

Answer (score 0):

$CONTACTEMAIL$ is a macro for the contact object, referencing to the attribute "email". Your command "notify-service-by-mail" will be assigned to such a contact as "service_notification_command" and that contact assigned to a service then (or via contactgroup). So once a notification happens, all required information is available and the core will translate the macro $CONTACTEMAIL$ to the real value and pass the converted string to the shell for execution then.

I would go for 2 options

- use implied inheritance (http://docs.icinga.org/latest/en/objectinheritance.html), and only define contacts for the host, and not the service below. the configuration parser will recognise that contacts should be inherited and your services will get only the related host's assigned contacts then. Though, this may get ugly in terms of not wanting to notify the host alerts to the same contacts as for the service themselves.
- making this more dynamic, i.e. setting service contacts based on their hostname, i would suggest using a config (generation) tool, allowing you e.g. manipulate the service->host relation with the defined contacts then. Though, there seems not really a generic solution out there... I would give LConf a try with the ldap tree itsself, but not sure if this would work out here, rather than writing a custom script, or use some puppet magic.

Comment: I use make and m4 to generate my Nagios definitions; Nagios definitions tend to be repetitive and verbose, so this works well.